# Java: send more than one image file from client to server using socket

Tags: java, sockets, file-io

I want to send more than one image file from client to server for this I write the code in my application, but it will send only one image.
In client application one frame is there and in server application also there is a frame to start/stop the server.

One more problem is there when Client application send the image file then this image file shown on server computer but when I try to open this image file then nothing is there but when I close server application(server frame) then I am able to see the image.

code:

client site:

```
public void sendPhotoToServer(String str){ // str is image location
    try {
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(str);
        byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
        int readData;
        while((readData=input.read(buffer))!=-1){
        dos.write(buffer,0,readData); // dos is DataOutputStream
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }       
}
```

In server side this code is running into thread:

```
public void run() {
while (true) {
            try {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                fis = new FileOutputStream("C:\\"+(s1++)+".jpg"); // fis is FileOutputStream
                while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0){ //count is a integer and 'in' is InputStream
                fis.write(buffer, 0, count); 
                fis.flush();    
                }
                } catch (Exception e) {}
}
}
```

**Problem:**

1. only 1st image is copying which is send by the client.
2. I am able to see this Image only when I close the server application.

no exception is there and i call **sendPhotoToServer** method in other class consecutively to send all the image file as:

```
if (photoSourcePath != null) {
                            clientClass.sendPhotoToServer(photoSourcePath+"\\"+rowData.get(5));
                        }
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? And how do you call `sendPhotoToServer`?

Comment: no exception is there.In other java class I call this sendPhotoToServe method as: if (photoSourcePath != null) {
        clientClass.sendPhotoToServer(photoSourcePath+"\\"+rowData.get(5));
       }

Comment: Since you catch exception without doing anything, are you sure? And are you calling `sendPhotoToServer` in a loop? Also, please edit the question to add the relevant code, and not put it in a comment.

Comment: ya no exception is there. exactly i an calling sendPhotoToServer method into loop. Client have some images into folder and when he select that folder then my application send all the images to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server side should stop the thread when its job is done. The `while` loop just keeps running forever and keeps the stream open (that's why you see the image when you shut down the server, the threads only stops then).

Try changing the server side to this:

```
public void run() {
    boolean processing = true;
    while (processing) {
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            fis = new FileOutputStream("C:\\" + (s1++) + ".jpg"); // fis is
                                                                  // FileOutputStream
            while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0) { // count is a integer
                                                    // and 'in' is
                                                    // InputStream
                fis.write(buffer, 0, count);
                fis.flush();

            }
            processing = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            processing = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: actually I not need to stop this while loop forever. because this is not for one client. One client send some image after that some other client also able to send images so it need to run for forever.

Comment: or after sending 2 or 3 image client want to send some more images after two or three hour then every time i need to start and stop the server. But server application will run 24 hours.